# Как одним запросом создать строку в расписании?

Tags: mysql

Необходимо создать расписание врачей в привычном виде:
`ФИО врача|время приема в пн|время приема во вт|время приема в ср|` и т.д.
У меня получается вытащить только ФИО врача и время приема для одного дня.

```
SELECT CONCAT(doctor.last_name," ",doctor.name) AS name_doc,
       CONCAT(times.t_begin,"-",times.t_end) AS time_doc
FROM doctor,times,timetables
WHERE doctor.id_doctor=timetables.id_doctor
      AND times.id_time=timetables.id_time;
```

Подскажите, как модифицировать?
Ссылка на бд http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7cbc4/5

Comment: Используй джойны

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Два варианта. Один сколько дней, столько join'ов (по два день):

```
select CONCAT(d.last_name, " ",d.name) "ФИО врача", 
  CONCAT(ifnull(t1.t_begin,""), if(t1.t_begin is null,""," - "), ifnull(t1.t_end,"")) "пн",
  CONCAT(ifnull(t2.t_begin,""), if(t2.t_begin is null,""," - "), ifnull(t2.t_end,"")) "вт",
  CONCAT(ifnull(t3.t_begin,""), if(t3.t_begin is null,""," - "), ifnull(t3.t_end,"")) "ср",
  CONCAT(ifnull(t4.t_begin,""), if(t4.t_begin is null,""," - "), ifnull(t4.t_end,"")) "чт",
  CONCAT(ifnull(t5.t_begin,""), if(t5.t_begin is null,""," - "), ifnull(t5.t_end,"")) "пт",
  CONCAT(ifnull(t6.t_begin,""), if(t6.t_begin is null,""," - "), ifnull(t6.t_end,"")) "сб",
  CONCAT(ifnull(t7.t_begin,""), if(t7.t_begin is null,""," - "), ifnull(t7.t_end,"")) "вс"
from  doctor d 
  left join timetables tt1 on tt1.id_doctor = d.id_doctor and tt1.id_day = 1
    left join times t1 on tt1.id_time = t1.id_time
  left join timetables tt2 on tt2.id_doctor = d.id_doctor and tt2.id_day = 2
    left join times t2 on tt2.id_time = t2.id_time
  left join timetables tt3 on tt3.id_doctor = d.id_doctor and tt3.id_day = 3
    left join times t3 on tt3.id_time = t3.id_time
  left join timetables tt4 on tt4.id_doctor = d.id_doctor and tt4.id_day = 4
    left join times t4 on tt4.id_time = t4.id_time
  left join timetables tt5 on tt5.id_doctor = d.id_doctor and tt5.id_day = 5
    left join times t5 on tt5.id_time = t5.id_time
  left join timetables tt6 on tt6.id_doctor = d.id_doctor and tt6.id_day = 6
    left join times t6 on tt6.id_time = t6.id_time
  left join timetables tt7 on tt7.id_doctor = d.id_doctor and tt7.id_day = 7
    left join times t7 on tt7.id_time = t7.id_time
order by 1;
```

Второй с группировкой:

```
select CONCAT(d.last_name, " ",d.name) "ФИО врача", 
group_concat(if(tt.id_day = 1,concat(ifnull(t.t_begin,""),if(t.t_begin is null,""," - "),ifnull(t.t_end,"")),"") SEPARATOR "") "пн",
group_concat(if(tt.id_day = 2,concat(ifnull(t.t_begin,""),if(t.t_begin is null,""," - "),ifnull(t.t_end,"")),"") SEPARATOR "") "вт",
group_concat(if(tt.id_day = 3,concat(ifnull(t.t_begin,""),if(t.t_begin is null,""," - "),ifnull(t.t_end,"")),"") SEPARATOR "") "ср",
group_concat(if(tt.id_day = 4,concat(ifnull(t.t_begin,""),if(t.t_begin is null,""," - "),ifnull(t.t_end,"")),"") SEPARATOR "") "чт",
group_concat(if(tt.id_day = 5,concat(ifnull(t.t_begin,""),if(t.t_begin is null,""," - "),ifnull(t.t_end,"")),"") SEPARATOR "") "пт",
group_concat(if(tt.id_day = 6,concat(ifnull(t.t_begin,""),if(t.t_begin is null,""," - "),ifnull(t.t_end,"")),"") SEPARATOR "") "сб",
group_concat(if(tt.id_day = 7,concat(ifnull(t.t_begin,""),if(t.t_begin is null,""," - "),ifnull(t.t_end,"")),"") SEPARATOR "") "вс"
from doctor d
  left join timetables tt on d.id_doctor = tt.id_doctor
    left join times t on tt.id_time = t.id_time
group by d.id_doctor
order by 1;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7cbc4/23

В зависимости от заполненности расписания и количества докторов один из запросов может быть немного быстрее. Я бы выбрал первый вариант, но тут дело вкуса.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю это то что Вам надо. Без ручных джойнов для каждого времени.

```
SELECT t.name_doc, GROUP_CONCAT(t.time_doc ORDER BY t.id_day SEPARATOR ", ") as work_time
  FROM (
    SELECT doctor.id_doctor, CONCAT(doctor.last_name," ",doctor.name) AS name_doc, days.id_day,
      CONCAT(days.name_day," ",times.t_begin,"-",times.t_end) AS time_doc 
      FROM doctor 
        JOIN timetables ON doctor.id_doctor=timetables.id_doctor
        JOIN times ON times.id_time=timetables.id_time
        JOIN days ON timetables.id_day=days.id_day
  ) as t
GROUP BY t.id_doctor
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7cbc4/32/0